# How to run software in terminal offline?

Tags: terminal, safety

I would like to run a flatpak program offline through the terminal (flatpak spoty runs as sudo!). I am looking for a simple command like:
"runoffline" flatpak run application.

What would be the fastest/best/safest way to ensure, that programs do not connect to the internet?

Comment: If you want to disable internet access to the flatpak app then read this: [How to block internet access to certain programs on Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/550276/how-to-block-internet-access-to-certain-programs-on-linux)

Comment: The `firejail` and `unshare -n` approaches given behind that link are in line with approaches I was suggesting in comments on the prior (closed-as-off-topic) SO iteration of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnecting the computer from your network would be 100% effective and also a reasonably fast/quick solution. As for "best", you haven't provided any criteria by which that should be measured